# clear FormData() in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following function for uploading images to a server using jQuery Ajax:

```
function(file,f){
    data = new FormData();
    var ids = file[f].name._unique();
    data.append('file',file[f]);
    data.append('index',ids);
    $(".dfiles[rel='"+ids+"']").find(".progress").show();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:this.config.uploadUrl,
        data:data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(rponse){
            //Success stuff here
            });
    });
}
```

In the section with `data.append('file', file[f]);` we're appending stuff to `data`. I'd like to be able to clear everything out from `data` from a different function. Is this possible? 
I could define `data` as `window.data` to make it global, but what would I do from there?

Comment: looks global to me with the little bit of code you posted.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any way to do it. The only method the `FormData` object has is `append`. Why do you need to do this, rather than just reassign the variable?

Comment: `data = null` would not work??

Answer (score -1):

Careful about declaring variables without 'var'. Your 'data' variable is global in your sample. Try using strict mode to safeguard against this. Otherwise, it should work fine. 'data' will be redefined every time you call the function.